# variable length dictionary as iterator in nested loops [Python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, runtime-error

I have a dictionary and a nested for loop as follows:

```
dictionary = {container: {row: [(tuple), (tuple)]}}

for box in box_df.index:
   for container in container_df.index:
      for row in dictionary[container].keys():
         if condition:
             dictionary[container][row + 1] = [(tuple)]
```

What I need is, if a new row is added I want to try it before moving to the box in order. If I use `continue` after conditional it returns a Runtime Error because the iterator has changed size. If I use `break` it moves to the next box.

I am kinda stuck.

Comment: `row` is a dictionary key, what is `row+1`?

Comment: if `row+1` doesn't exist in keys add as a new key.

Comment: for further help you will need to provide input and output examples. I do not understand what you need from the question

Answer (score 0):

in order to avoid the iterator changing during the loop, consume it to list and then iterate over the list

```
for row in list(dictionary[container].keys()):
```

Comment: This fixes runtime error issue, but doesn't do what I really want. It moves onto the next box first.